# Photoshop works extremely bad after Wacom Installation

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Recently I bought a Wacom Intuos online and I installed the driver which came with it. I drew with it, but because I did not like it, I sold it.

Now Photoshop CC works extremely bad (Laggs even when I build a shape and the selection tool makes wierd selections). I have a Lenovo y50 with 250gb SSD i7 4700MQ 8gb ram. It should work flawless, because before this happened, I had no problem with it.

Is it possible to be from the Wacom tablet or could it be from something else?

If you know the solution please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome Phil! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding technical support.

Comment: Thank you Luciano for letting me know ! I will close this when i find out how.

Comment: If you open up the device manager and look into graphics adapters, do you find any additional drivers installed?

Answer (score 0):

All the problems began when Adobe changed Photoshop to use Microsoft system API's. Try this:

1. Disable the `Windows Ink` option in the Wacom preferences.
2. Create a text file in a text editor with the following lines:

   ```
   # Use WinTab
   UseSystemStylus 0
   ```
3. Save the file as a plain text file named `PSUserConfig.txt`, and save the file into the Photoshop settings folder: `C:\Users\[User Name]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2014\Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 Settings\`

References: https://forums.adobe.com/message/6471567#6471567